# maintain vs sustain

Tags: difference

What are the similarities and differences? Abbreviate **maintain** as M and **sustain** as S. S2 [(= definition 2 of S) appears absent in any definition of M, but does M1 = S3, M2 = S1, M3 = S4?

[**maintain**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/maintain) =  1. Cause or enable (a condition or situation) to continue
2. Provide with necessities for life or existence
3. [reporting verb] State something strongly to be the case; assert:

[**sustain**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sustain) = 
1. Strengthen or support physically or mentally
2. Undergo or suffer (something unpleasant, especially an injury):
3. Cause to continue for an extended period or without interruption:
4. Uphold, affirm, or confirm the justice or validity of:

Comment: They may be somewhat related, but they are certainly not "equal"; _aver_ and _affirm_ are not synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

*Maintain* means to do what is needed to ensure something stays a certain state or quality, often the equivalent of "to keep up" or "to take care of."  *Maintain* applies if what is needed to keep things up is a periodic or occasional activity.

*Sustain* means to hold something at a certain level.  It implies that what is being held would quickly fall or fade if not sustained - something that is *maintained* would decay over a longer time if neglected.  Things that are *sustained* require continuous, foreground effort.

*Sustain* can also mean "to absorb" or *to take a blow/injury/damage* - *I've sustained a cut to my knee.* but *maintain* never means this.

Answer (score 1):

"Sustain" tends to be more passive than "maintain." That's not always the case, and there are definitely cases and contexts where they could be functionally interchangeable, but in general the typical uses are nearly opposites.

The concept that jumped to my mind when reading this question was that of "sustainable energy" (AKA renewable or "green" energy), that which comes from renewable sources like solar or wind power. The idea of "sustain" here is that those sources will be able to continue on indefinitely without faltering: the sun will continue to--on average--shine, regardless of the circumstances.

On the other hand, "maintenance" is applicable more to things that wouldn't sustain themselves. For example, your car needs regular maintenance or else it *will* begin to falter, or break down. A person has to fix and replace things on it.

They're similar in that both have to do with how well a task holds up over the passage of time, and because of that they can sometimes be used in each other's places, but ultimately the difference, at least in my mind, relates to how much intervention is required to keep something going.

Answer (score 0):

**Maintain** :

To keep something in a certain state unaltered reserving it for a special use.

**Sustain**:

To supply or support with nutriment or any kind of assistance to keep something extended in their validity for a longer duration.

In both cases there is an action of keeping something in a good condition but the means are different .
Objects are mainly maintained while communities , organizations and people are sustained.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Could you add your source for these meanings?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to think about it in the way where: sustain = provide sustenance vs maintain = provide maintenance.

**Puppy example:**
If you provide sustenance to your puppy ie. feeding him dog food, you are sustaining his life.
If you provide maintenance ie. checkups at the vet, you are maintaining his health.

To summarize, "sustain" is a continuous/constant provision of resources to ensure existence, "maintain" is periodic intervention to restore something that has deteriorated over time.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, and thanks for your answer! A dictionary reference would help make it even more useful. Please take a minute to review our [**tour**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. We hope you'll answer more questions and ask some of your own.