# Sustain vs Maintain (extended from other question)

Tags: word-choice, difference

I've read this [Q&A](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38812/maintain-vs-sustain).

In the answers from this question. One of answers says,

> Sustain:
>
> To supply or support with nutriment or any kind of assistance to keep something extended in their validity for a longer duration.

and the other answer says,

> "Sustain" tends to be more passive than "maintain."

To me, it seems a little contradictory because support implies active meaning in my mind.

Furthermore, if I search for "Who sustains for Windows", Google doesn't show the result that I anticipated: "Microsoft" well
It only shows me proper result when I searched for "Who maintains Windows".

It's slightly akward to me for result of google, as I thought the word "sustain" as synonym of the word "support".

Can anyone explain this please?

Comment: Which definition of “sustain” from a credible dictionary do you think applies to “Microsoft sustains Windows”? Some words may be effectively synonymous in some contexts, but not in others.

Comment: Also "who sustains **for** Windows" doesn't make sense; you don't sustain *for* something else.  It is probably more common to see it in the passive voice: X *is sustained by* Y.

Comment: @ColleenV At very first before I read the link above that I quoted, I read link below https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-words-retain-sustain-and-maintain. And after I listen to your comment, I backed again to dictionary, it says, “support something physically or mentally”. Is “sustain” can only be applied to living things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(this is just my personal opinion, not taken from any sources)

to sustain is to give *Something physical* to another Thing so that it can continue doing some [desired] Act.

Microsoft (the company) isn't giving windows (the software) any physical things, they're only giving work/manpower to windows (the software)
that's why it may seem odd.

But it can work if you say "Microsoft (the company) sustains the windows department (the department the works on the software)"
because here maybe Microsoft is giving that department some money, or some employees.

"They sustained the war" ? Works (wars need soldiers)
"They sustained the war efforts" ? Not so much (war efforts don't need soldiers, because war efforts are themselves sustenance to wars)
"They sustained the nutrients" ? just no (nutrients are a sustenance, they can't be sustained"

Comment: Thanks for answer! Now it's clarified much more, even if it's your opinion. I'll aware of that.